# Generating new model is not possible after creating model in active admin for that in ROR

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

When i am trying to generate model using 
'rails g model certificate'
but it shows me error that 'top required' after creating new model in active admin for that using 
'rails g active_admin:resource certificates'.
Any one know about this error? What should i do first? create model first and than should i go for generate model in active admin? 
Thanks.

Comment: Could you paste the whole error along the stack trace?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, First you have to generate model using

```
rails g model certificate
```

Then you can add that model to active admin with

```
rails g active_admin:resource certificate
```

We can only add existing models to active_admin

Here we have best tutorial about active admin http://railscasts.com/episodes/284-active-admin

Comment: Thanks. The problem is that i used active admin model name as certificates instead of certificate. So now its working.